# Giving simple js pagination to a Ajax generated table

Tags: javascript, ajax, drupal, pagination, html-table

I have a ajax call in drupal which generates and brings back a entire table right under where I click. The tables are large, so I want them paginated. I don't have time for server side pagination and I also need to apply it in a lot of places.

I found this http://code.google.com/p/one-simple-table-paging/ a very easy to use one and should solve my purpose.

I managed to use it in static html pages:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="oneSimpleTablePaging-1.0.js"></script>

<table class="tableToPaginate">
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th><th>Name</th>
    </tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) { ?>                            
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i ?></td><td><?php echo "name" . $i ?></td>
        </tr>                        
        <?php } ?>
</table>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.tableToPaginate').oneSimpleTablePagination({rowsPerPage: 20});
   });        
</script>
```

but when I use the same technique for my ajax generated tables giving them the same class and calling the script in page.tpl, php I don't see the pagination

```
echo '<table id="ajaxcustomerdata" class="account_info tableToPaginate">';
.....
```

I am new with ajax and js; please help me out.

Comment: it seems that document. ready wont work for later generated(by ajax) html's . So what should i use?

Comment: use the ajax callback method, it should fire once the ajax call is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995377/giving-simple-js-pagination-to-a-ajax-generated-table) javascript plugin for this purpose — very powerfull and simple jQuery plugin.

Adding pagginated AJAX table is just a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": '../ajax/sources/arrays.txt'
    } );
} );
```

Or you can [turn usual html table to DataTable table](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/dom.html):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable();
} );
```

[More info on this example](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html).

Comment: thanks fro leading to the wonderful library. But i already have 1 the problem i am facing is the the $(document).ready(function(){}) is triggered at first time the page is loaded, but my table is "tableToPaginate" is inserted to the doc later by ajax so it is left un decorated by the function. I want to know if there is any jquery /js event that triggers after the document is changed by ajax?

Comment: Call it inside callback from AJAX-response

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved. I just called the function inside the if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){} of my ajax function. it is working now